# Why wont my appendChild work?

Tags: javascript, element, appendchild, createelement

I have a little javascript app set up here: http://jsfiddle.net/faYMH/

What i want it to do is add a

```
<div><h1>Hi there and greetings!</h1></div>
```

after

```
<div id='org_div1' onclick="addElement()">Hello</div>
```

using

```
<a href="#" onClick="addElement()" >add some</a>
```

(actually, what i want is for the onClick to go directly in the

So can anyone correct my code or provide some input?

(My next step is to also add a remove div, add an id to the new div with id + i++ )

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your jsFiddle, addElement was scoped to inside the document ready handler and thus wasn't available to the click handler.  I've modified the settings in the jsFiddle (without changing any code) to not have your code wrapped that way and it works for me now: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/XVDYa/.

I changed the jsFiddle settings to "No-Library (pure JS)" and to "no wrap (head)".  It's the second setting that really makes the difference here.

Comment: Oh wow great! Thanks for realizing that!

So now im on to the next step... if you could take a quick look thats be great.. each added div should have a file upload field and a unique name (file + i++) .. I wrote the basis http://jsfiddle.net/faYMH/10/ If you can take a really quick look and correct the syntax to see why it isnt working??

Thanksk you soo much

Comment: @Jonah: Try opening a new question for that. (though I see the problem)

Comment: You see the problem @icktoofay ?? Please please just post, guaranteed +1 :)

Comment: @Jonah: It's a different (though related) question; it deserves its own question.

Comment: @ictoofay - youre right, heres the question , Easy +1 ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688320/how-do-i-appendchild-a-file-upload-field-with-i  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

That's a quirk of JSFiddle. It wraps all of your code in a closure, so `onclick` handlers can't access your function. Either export the function into the global scope:

```
window.addElement=addElement;
```

Or change the little drop down in JSFiddle from "onLoad" to "no wrap (head)" or "no wrap (body)". While you're at it, you might want to change "Mootools" to "No-Library (pure JS)".

Comment: Interesting observation; I had never thought to check for that in the original version's output.