# How do I appendChild a file upload field with i++?

Tags: javascript, appendchild, createelement

I im creating a javascript file using addElemend and childAppend to add a new

Ive written the code here http://jsfiddle.net/faYMH/18/

But for some reason it isnt working. If I replace the file upload field within the innerhtml with a simple  it does work!

Can anyone spot the problem / put in some input how to accomplish what i want?

Thanks!

Jonah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few things wrong with that.

### JSFiddle problems

First of all, you still have the framework settings set to "onLoad" and "Mootools". You'll want it to be one of the "no wrap" options and "No-Library (pure JS)". Secondly, you're putting the script in a `script` tag in the HTML pane. There's a JavaScript pane specifically for JavaScript.

### JavaScript problems

You have some inline HTML in your JavaScript:

```
newDiv.innerHTML = "<input type="file" name="file1 + i++" />";
```

You're using double quotes (`"`) for your JavaScript string as well as inside the HTML. Try using single quotes for the JavaScript string delimiters, like this:

```
newDiv.innerHTML = '<input type="file" name="file1' + (i++) + ' />';
```

The HTML inside the string is also not valid. It will try to generate HTML like this:

```
<input type="file" name="file10 />
```

There's no closing quote. Fix that:

```
newDiv.innerHTML = '<input type="file" name="file1' + (i++) + '" />';
```

You might also want to remove the stray `1`, though it doesn't break the script.

### Result

[Here it is](http://jsfiddle.net/faYMH/24/), after these changes and a few more.